# Adding variables to html file_get_contains

Tags: php, html

I have an API with SLIM. I'm sending an HTML File with PHPMailer to the html. Really the HTML is the mail content. The problem is that the HTML should have php variables. Right now, I am trying to access an external PHP file and add the variables from there but I can't.

Here is my PHP code;

```
<?php
$app->post('/email', 'authenticate', function() use($app) {
  checkParams(array('userid', 'emailtemplate'));

  $userid = $app->request->post('userid');
  $emailtemplate = $app->request->post('emailtemplate');

  $query="SELECT * FROM App_User WHERE UserID = '$userid'";
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  $UserLOCode = mysql_result($result, 0, "UserLOCode");
  //AND MORE VARIABLES USED ON THE HTML

  //CODE NOT NEEDED
  $mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('http://mymloapp.com/api/controllers/emailtemplate_1.php'), dirname(__FILE__));

//CODE NOT NEEDED 
});
?>
```

And here is the HTML file:

```
<p>
  Hi <?php echo $LoanOfficerFName;?>:
</p>
   //MORE AND MORE CODE WITH MORE VARIABLES
```

How can I make the variables work?

Comment: You might be able to do this by retrieving the contents to a variable then using `eval($variable)` somehow. `eval()`, though, is generally evil. My solution to a similar problem was to create a template like this `Dear [[firstname]]...` and use `preg_replace()` to find and replace `[[firstname]]` in the template.

Comment: @HoboSapiens It worked used the preg_replace()

Answer (score 0):

I used `preg_replace()`. Exactly like @HoboSapiens told me.